# Playing youtube link sound only without showing video in Xcode

Tags: xcode, parsing, xcode4, youtube

I am writing an application in Xcode. Now I wanna play a music from youtube link without showing the video!! I wanna only play the sound of the video. So can you help me in the code. right now I am only showing the music list from my site on the table view and also showing the link. but couldn't plug the youtube feature!!

Thanks in advance.